# Synchronizing stored procedures in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, synchronization

I have two applications, both of them are using the same stored procedure in MySQL.
I would like this procedure to be synchronized, that is while one applications calls it, the other one has to wait.

Is there a way to do this without altering the codes of the applications (that is only modifying the stored procedure)?

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely do this within the stored procedure without changing your application code, but bear in mind that you're introducing locking issues and the possibility of timeouts.

Use [`GET_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock) and [`RELEASE_LOCK()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-lock) to take care of the synchronization. Run `GET_LOCK` to perform the synchronization at the start of your stored procedure, and `RELEASE_LOCK` once you're done:

```
IF (GET_LOCK('lock_name_for_this_SP', 60)) THEN
   .... body of SP
   RELEASE_LOCK('lock_name_for_this_SP');
ELSE
   .... lock timed out
END IF
```

You'll also need to take care that your application timeouts are longer than the lock timeout so you don't incur other problems.